# How to find the URL of a SharePoint web application given the url of a Site within that

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

I need to find the URL of the web application of a given Site (say I have an url http://code/sites/java. Given the url of this site collection i need the URL of the web app that hosts this site collection. In this case it will be http://code. ) Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. If you have an SPWeb object use its [Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.site.aspx) property. If you have an SPSite object use its [WebApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.webapplication.aspx) property. If you don't have either, [create an SPSite object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466911.aspx) from that URL.
2. From the SPWebApplication object use the [AlternateUrls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.alternateurls.aspx) property.
3. From the [SPAlternateUrlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spalternateurlcollection.aspx) object retrieve the SPAlternateUrl for your desired zone.
4. From the [SPAlternateUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spalternateurl_members.aspx) object get the actual URL.

The reason why you need to go through the alternate URL collection is because of the alternate access mappings you can [associate with a web application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287734.aspx). For example all web apps start with Default, which can be extended to Intranet, Extranet, etc.

Remember to use dispose with the above objects as necessary.

Comment: powershell: `(site.webapplication.alternateurls | ? {$_.urlzone -eq "Default|Intranet|Internet|Custom|Extranet" }).publicurl` OR `(site.webapplication.alternateurls | ? {$_.urlzone -eq "Default|Intranet|Internet|Custom|Extranet" }).incomingurl`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string path= HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority
```

You will get the url of the Web Application